# Android: Is it possible to be notified when a calendar event is starting/ending?

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to be notified when a calendar event is starting or ending ?

What I'd like to do is register to some kind of event, Intent or some other listener and to be notified when an event is starting or ending.

Comment: Take a look inside the standard android Calendar to see if it broadcasts any intents like that when an event happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to be notified when a calendar event is starting or ending ?

The Android OS does not have a calendar. Hence, the Android SDK does not have any APIs related to calendars.